# Use array in loop in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays, loops

In general: I need to retrieve values from an array to submit those values as indices to a function.

More specific: I want to create figures, which contain subfigures. These subfigures are loaded from mysubfigures.pdf. The order of the subfigures is saved in a seperate list `ggg`. I made a minimal example below.

This is the part that doesn't work and where I need your help: `page=\ggg(\subfigure)`

I want it to be like `page=64` when `\subfigure`is`1`, `page=61` when `\subfigure`is`2`, and so on.

*(I have looked at some similar questions on stackexchange but I don't understand the answers.)*

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjob}

\begin{document}

\newarray\ggg
\readarray{ggg}{64&61&41}
\ggg(1)

    \foreach \subfig in {1,2,3}
    {
        %This is Figure \subfig
        \includegraphics[page=\ggg(\subfig)]{./mysubfigures.pdf};
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why can't you just write `\foreach \subfigure in {64,61,41}` and use `page=\subfigure`?

Comment: Side note: Using `\subfigure` as a loop "variable" might be dangerous.

Comment: Just edited the MWE to remove typos and wrong `tikzpicture` env

Comment: What about avoiding using arrays and using lists instead?
`\foreach[count=\i] \pg in {64,61,41} {Subfigure~\i, Page~\pg: \includegraphics[page=\pg]{mysubfigures} }` If you elaborate on why you want to use arrays we could give you more help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is that `arrayjob` does some nasty stuff to get the value out of the array and this is not compatible with how `\includegraphics` handles its arguments.

There are two solutions:

## 1. expand and then use

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjob}

\begin{document}

    \newarray\ggg
    \readarray{ggg}{64&61&41}
    \ggg(1)

    \foreach \subfig in {1,2,3}
    {
        %This is Figure \subfig
        \checkggg(\subfig)
        \includegraphics[page=\cachedata]{mysubfigures};
    }
\end{document}
```

Here `\checkARRAYNAME(INDEX)` will save the value in the macro `\cachedata` so we can use it in the arguments normally since that will not need special treatment to rewrite to the value.

## 2. use pgfmath's arrays

Since you are using `tikz` the package `pgfmath` is already loaded and it is able to understand arrays.
Simply do:

```
\def\ggg{{64,61,41}} % <- your array is just a list    

    \foreach \i in {0,1,2} % 0-based indexes
    {
        %This is Figure \i
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pg}{\ggg[\i]} % <- array notation ARRAY[INDEX]
        \includegraphics[page=\pg]{mysubfigures}
    }
```

## A third way

Unless you really need arrays somewhere else in your document,
you do not need them here as you can just exploit the excellent `\foreach` syntax:

```
\foreach[count=\i] \pg in {64,61,41} {
    Subfigure~\i, Page~\pg:
    \includegraphics[page=\pg]{mysubfigures}
}
```